# On booting I get Grub menu instead of splash page

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I am running Ubuntu MATE 15.04 on HP Spectre X360 [no dual boot]

I have had troubles with booting and have been able to solve Software Updater Problems getting rid of redundant kernel files. I am running /boot/config-3.19.0-28-generic because that seems to be the only version that works with the Spectre X360: - I get a freeze problem on boot with newer kernels.

When I turn on the laptop I get the Ubuntu Grub Menu with the following options:

Ubuntu

Advanced options for Ubuntu

System Set Up

I click on "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and get a window with the kernel and the recovery mode. When I click on the non recovery mode the splash screen comes up and everything works as normal [and very fast I might add]. so, there is a problem with grub.

I have 2 inconsistent files which might have something to do with that, but, while I can follow steps that other more knowledgeable users suggest on forums such as this, I am after all only an end-user. The files and the discrepancies between etc/default/grub.ucf and etc/default/grub.ucf.dist are as follows:

**etc/default/grub.ucf**

10. GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
11. GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"

12.

**etc/default/grub.ucf.dist**

10. GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
11. GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
12. GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"
  13.

The lines in grub.ucf were altered to successfully solve a sound problem with Ubuntu installed on HP Spectre X360. I've had no other problem with booting [although before I got rid of the other kernel versions I was getting a recovery mode splash page first up, with a separate cursor that did not allow me to enter my password in the GUI. To get out of that I discovered ctrl/alt/delete worked to take me to the Ubuntu Grub Menu].

By the way, after each change I have always then run the "sudo update-grub" command.

Can anyone please point me to a solution. In a way, it's an extra layer of security for the data, but I already have a double password step.

Cheers,

James